# How to update html document using feather js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I have a service that I call after every 5 secs to return data from postgres table, now I want this data to be displayed on html document

app.js

```
const stats=app.service('test_view');
// console.log(stats);
function getstats(){
stats.find().then(response=>{
    console.log('data is ',response.data)});};
setInterval(function() {
  getstats();
}, 5000);
// console.log(stats);
```

stats.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stats</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='stats'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is running fine and I am getting results in console, I am using feather.js now I want these results to be displayed in div tag of html.Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the feathers service from the browser.  You can do this a number of different ways (as a REST call, with the feathers client, etc.).

```
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.1.4/core.min.js"></script>
         <script src="//unpkg.com/@feathersjs/client@4.0.0-pre.3/dist/feathers.js"></script>
         <script src="//unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // @feathersjs/client is exposed as the `feathers` global.
      const app = feathers();
      app.configure(feathers.rest('http://localhost:3000').axios(axios));
      app.service('test_view').find();
      })
      .then(data => {
        // do something with data
      });
    </script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
 </html>
```

A lot of this depends on what (if anything) you're using for your front-end implementation.  This sets up a minimal feathersjs/client using axios for REST, with no authentication, and calls your service (on port 3000) and gets the payload.

To do this every 5 seconds is outside the scope of feathers and up to how you build your web app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how you could change the contents of that div when you get data back from your remote call.

```js
// Simulate your remote call... ignore this part.
const stats = {}
stats.find = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve({
  data: 'here is some data ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US')
}));

// Div you want to change.
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('stats');

// Get the data
function getstats () {
  stats.find().then(response => {
    console.log('data is ', response.data);
    // Update the contents of the div with your data.
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = response.data;
  });
}  
 
setInterval(function() {
  getstats();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stats</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='stats'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It gives me this error 
 D:\Fiverr\pdxoptions\feathers\src\app.js:53
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('stats');
                   ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: @user3052682 are you executing your JS in the browser or with node?

Comment: I am executing it through node, feather js

Comment: can you let me know how can I make it work using node

Comment: You can not update elements in the browser from node. The code above must run in the browser.

Comment: there has to be a way, I have setup an app using feathers js, what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: feathers.js is for the backend. To update info in the browser you also need to run code on the frontend. I.e. in the browser.